# Read Access doesnt allows viewing Webparts and Navigation on SPS2013 Homepage

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-server, permissions, navigation

Issue: Permission to Access Webparts, Navigation on homepage with Read access or Full access not working for users

Environment: SharePoint 2013

Users part of Read access only are facing issue, they cant view:

a) Top Navigation

b) Data presented in List Webpart, Announcement Webpart, News Webpart on the homepage

I tried removing the Read permission and adding it again, no good.

Therefore, as a test later upgraded from Read permission to Full permission, still the same.

Please suggest what best can be done to get users access Intranet homepage with Read permission.

Answer (score 0):

If your Top navigation has the link of subistes, chack whether the user has access to the subsite. Else if the links in the top navigation are just pages, check whether the user have permission for those page at the item level.

Similarly, check wehther the users have access in the list level and in the list item level.

If everything is fine, check whether the users have access to Style library, Theme library, Master page gallery and other hidden lists.

The issue should be mostly based on permission. Check the permission at all the levels, Root site level, sub site level, list level and list item level. Also check whether any target audience set for the webparts.

Comment: Pls note, its not only top navigation. Even Webparts  data is not visible. I `ve tried removing permission and adding again as stated in my first post. Any spot on steps that can help?

Comment: Did you check the permission at item level?